# error parsing in haskell code

Tags: haskell, recursion

My haskell code goes as follows :

```
module Lain where
let value = 0 
divideBy ::(Ord a, Num a)=>a -> a -> a
divideBy _ 0 = 0
divideBy num den
    | (num - den) >= 0 = do 
        value = value + 1
        return divideBy (num-den) den
    | otherwise = value
```

The error goes on loading the haskell Lain.hs file is :

`app/Lain.hs:18:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.`

Not able to interpret where I am going wrong, seems to me more of a logical mistake. My code wants to print the quotient given numerator and denominator. Please help as to what is exactly my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value = value + 1` isn’t a valid statement in a `do` block. The only valid statements are:

- A variable binding: `let pattern = expression`
- A monadic binding: `pattern <- expression`
- An expression that evaluates to a monadic action

However, you don’t need a `do` block because you don’t need monadic side effects to implement this function. Furthermore, `return` isn’t like `return` in an imperative language—it’s not a keyword that returns from the current function, but a function that creates an action that returns a value. It looks like your intent with `value = value + 1` was to mutate `value`, but there are no mutable variables in Haskell. (There are mutable reference types such as `IORef`, but you don’t need them here.)

So one solution is to simply use an expression:

```
divideBy :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
divideBy _ 0 = 0
divideBy num den
    | num - den >= 0 = 1 + divideBy (num - den) den
    | otherwise = 0
```

This says exactly what it means: the quotient of `num` and `den` is `0` if `den` is `0`; if `num - den >= 0`, then it’s 1 more than the quotient of `num - den` and `den`; otherwise it’s `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much !! It was really helpful !